# Column retrieved from database must be cast to numeric to be usable

Tags: r

If I retrieve the data from a database (a MySQL database with either RMariaDB or ODBC) I get errors while using the data as-is with multiple R functions (hist, boxplot, but not sd or summary):

```
Error in hist.default(lockout_per_hour$alarm_count) : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In pretty.default(range(x), n = breaks, min.n = 1) :
  Internal(pretty()): very small range.. corrected
```

If I just export that same data to a CSV file and import it in RStudio everything works, otherwise if I want to use the data from the database I have to cast it to numeric.

As requested, code:

```
library(DBI);
db <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'my-dns');

q_perHour = "SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(timestamp), '%H') hour, COUNT(*) count
FROM alarm
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp), DAY(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
LIMIT 100";

rs = dbSendQuery(db, q_perHour);
data <- dbFetch(rs);

hist(data$count); # KO
sd(data$count); # OK
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(hour = c("18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00", 
"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
"08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21"), count = structure(c(2.47032822920623e-323, 
4.94065645841247e-323, 3.95252516672997e-323, 3.95252516672997e-323, 
3.45845952088873e-323, 3.95252516672997e-323, 8.39911597930119e-323, 
1.48219693752374e-323, 3.95252516672997e-323, 3.45845952088873e-323, 
5.92878775009496e-323, 5.92878775009496e-323, 4.94065645841247e-323, 
5.43472210425371e-323, 2.47032822920623e-323, 1.97626258336499e-323, 
5.43472210425371e-323, 5.43472210425371e-323, 4.44659081257122e-323, 
9.38724727098368e-323, 5.92878775009496e-323, 6.91691904177745e-323, 
6.42285339593621e-323, 2.47032822920623e-323, 4.94065645841247e-323, 
8.89318162514244e-323, 4.44659081257122e-323, 8.39911597930119e-323, 
1.08694442085074e-322, 1.33397724377137e-322, 2.02566914794911e-322, 
1.13635098543487e-322, 1.24010477106153e-321, 9.40700989681733e-321, 
1.43279037293961e-322, 1.67982319586024e-322, 1.08694442085074e-322, 
4.44659081257122e-323, 7.90505033345994e-323, 5.92878775009496e-323, 
7.4109846876187e-323, 6.91691904177745e-323, 8.89318162514244e-323, 
5.92878775009496e-323, 9.88131291682493e-323, 7.90505033345994e-323, 
9.38724727098368e-323, 1.18575755001899e-322, 7.4109846876187e-323, 
1.23516411460312e-322, 1.23516411460312e-322, 1.13635098543487e-322, 
1.72922976044436e-322, 1.28457067918724e-322, 1.67982319586024e-322, 
1.72922976044436e-322, 9.38724727098368e-323, 2.12448227711736e-322, 
2.99403781379795e-321, 1.13635098543487e-322, 1.13635098543487e-322, 
7.90505033345994e-323, 8.39911597930119e-323, 9.38724727098368e-323, 
7.4109846876187e-323, 6.91691904177745e-323, 5.92878775009496e-323, 
8.89318162514244e-323, 6.42285339593621e-323, 6.91691904177745e-323, 
1.13635098543487e-322, 7.90505033345994e-323, 1.67982319586024e-322, 
2.27270197086973e-322, 1.87744945419674e-322, 7.90505033345994e-323, 
1.43279037293961e-322, 8.89318162514244e-323, 1.13635098543487e-322, 
1.23516411460312e-322, 1.03753785626662e-322, 1.28457067918724e-322, 
1.03753785626662e-322, 7.4109846876187e-323, 9.88131291682493e-323, 
1.08694442085074e-322, 3.45845952088873e-323, 7.4109846876187e-323, 
4.44659081257122e-323, 4.94065645841247e-323, 3.45845952088873e-323, 
2.96439387504748e-323, 5.43472210425371e-323, 5.43472210425371e-323, 
7.90505033345994e-323, 6.91691904177745e-323, 5.43472210425371e-323, 
7.90505033345994e-323, 8.39911597930119e-323, 7.11454530011395e-322
), class = "integer64")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

As suggested, the issue is remediated if I change the connection to:

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'my-dns', bigint='numeric');
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the data from the database?  Please provide the code and a sample of the data using `dput()` after you have successfully read it into R.

Comment: I would recommend you check out [`dplyr`][1]'s documentation as it relates to databases.   


  [1]: https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/

Comment: I just updated the question @jsb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the class "integer64" does not work well with the `hist()` function. Try modifying both variables to numeric:

```
library(dplyr)
data = mutate(data, hour = as.numeric(hour), count = as.numeric(count))
```

This works, although a warning is thrown for `hist(data$count)`:

> Warning messages: 1: In pretty.default(range(x), n = breaks, min.n =
>
> 1. :   Internal(pretty()): very small range.. corrected 2: In
>    plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) :   Internal(pretty()): very small
>    range.. corrected

This warning seems to be connected to the data itself, though.

Also, you can try using the `bigint` argument in `dbConnect()` set to "numeric". This governs how 64-bit integer data is returned.

Comment: Yes that's what I did to make the data workable from the database, but why I can't use the data as it is retrieved from the database? Can this be altered in the query itself? Can I use some automatic cast? What if this was not only one column but, say 100, should I have to cast that columns programmatically too? Can I tell the connector not to use integer64 or something like that? Also it is not just the hist function but also other plot functions like boxplot or plot.